# How to construct XCM message that transfers custom encoded call

Tags: xcm, xcmp, cross-chain

Suppose we have a message that transfers encoded call that looks as follows:

`call = Self::MintNickname.encode().into()`

How do we transfer it to another parachain via XCM in Rust snippet?
Another chain has the same pallet so it knows which call to perform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the ping pallet in the cumulus [here](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/tree/master/parachains/pallets/ping)

Comment: Thank you, I have. I am however confused about the runtime part. call: <T as Config>::RuntimeCall::from(Call::<T>::ping). I though I can use use Self:: but what i see is, that ping uses Call::